# How to move an element back to its original place without "location.reload" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game with a ball and when it touches the top of the screen you're out. I also have a system that calculates a score and a high score. I want the ball to be brought to its original position when you press OK on the confirm window.

Here's what I have so far:

**The score-calculating function:**

```
var score = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if(!paused)
        score++;
    diplayScore.innerHTML = "Score:\n" + score;
     var getHigh = displayHighScore.innerHTML = "High Score:" + highScore;
},1000);
```

**When you get out:**

```
if (characterTop <= 0) {
        if(score > highScore) {
            highScore = score;
         }
        if(confirm("Game over. Do you want to play again?") === true) {
            // Reset Game...
        }
        else {
           // Do Nothing...
        }           
    }
```

I've tried resetting the Game with `location.reload`, but it resets the high score as well, ruining the point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to **store your high score in `localStorage`**, as from your description, only high score is the value needed to be persisted. The rest of your program can be reset through page refresh, as what you're trying now.

You only need to add 'read high score from localStorage' when the game is loaded, and 'save high score into localStorage' if a new high score is obtained. Should be quite straightforward following the example below.

- [Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/jC9ms/) of `localStorage` read and write.
- [localStorage document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I've checked the links, but I still don't understand.

Maybe a code example would be nice?

Thanks so  much!

Comment: @Menmoe Can you check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5unjartb/2/ I've added some explanation in the code to help you understand

Comment: Thanks so much!
It all works accept it doesn't give a high score, it gives your previous score.
I've tried putting `if(highscore >= score)` as much as possible, but, to no avail.
I know you probably know what to do....

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Menmoe I think in your case it should be `if(highscore < score)`? Only update high score if the current score is higher, right?

Comment: I tried both of those... Maybe i put it in the wrong spot?